# Comparing two lists with order changes

Tags: c#, algorithm, comparison

I want to be able to compare two lists and to see if the values are in the same order.

For example if I have a table with a field and an order like :

```
Field -- Order

F1 -- 1

F2 -- 2

F3 -- 3

F4 -- 4
```

and another:

```
Field -- Order

F1 -- 3

F2 -- 2

F3 -- 1

F4 -- 4
```

I want to be able to return a list of all rows with a changed order, in this case it would be F1 and F3.

A way I thought of doing this was to compare the previous and next values of the Order Field and so if they are both different, than there has been a change in the order. I must also keep into account any added or removed value.

**ETA:** 
I want to clarify what I meant by taking into account a possible addition or removal.

Say the second table now looked like :

```
Field -- Order

F1 -- 1

F3 -- 3

F4 -- 4
```

because something has been removed. The order value hasn't changed but F3 will now be right after F1. Same for F4.

So I would want my result to show that F3 and F4 have changed.

Comment: Are `F1, F2, F3, F4...FN` always expected to be in the correct order?

Comment: @ChrisSinclair There isn't really a correct order.Think of it as a value which indicates which field is to be executed next.

Comment: For the post-edit example, can we consider *just* 3 or *just* 1 out of order?

Comment: @Dukeling I'm not sure I understand your question. In the post edit example, F4 hasn't really changed because it's still after F3 but F3 has changed because it is no longer after F2

Comment: You can say 3 has changed because it's no longer before 1, or 1 has changed because it's no longer after 3. You say 4 hasn't really changed in the comment, but you say it did change in the question.

Comment: I feel the question is NOT described clearly enough. If `Original: F1 F2 F3 F4` and later `F1 F4 F3`, what changes do you want to output?

Answer (score 1):

This will check for equality between 2 lists

```
bool AreSame = list1.SequenceEqual(list2);
```

this is to order them without repeating members:

```
var union = (from s in list1 select s).Union(from s1 in list2 select s1).OrderBy(x => x);
//this is based if its list of strings for example 
//this next you select some property
var union = (from s in list1 select s.SomeProperty).Union(from s1 in list2 select s1.SomeProperty).OrderBy(x => x);
```

this next will return an enemerable of boolean values where true represents the items that are diferent ex: if result is true,false,false,true   that means between the 2 lists the first and fourth element are diferent.

```
var some = list1.Zip(list2, (a, b) => a.SomeProperty != b.SomeProperty);
```

Comment: +1 for `Zip`... `list1.Zip(list2, (a, b) => new { a, b }).Where(x => x.a.Order != x.b.Order).Select(x => x.a.Field)` will do.

Answer (score 0):

I got a feeling this is a homework question :P so I will give you a half code answer ;).

**Edit: It doesn't actually matter to me :P**

```
List<int> checkList = new List<int>();

for (var i = 0; i < list1.Count; i++)
{
    if (list1[index] != list2[index])
    {
        checkList.Add(list1[index]);
    }
}
// checkList will be your answer.
```

**Edit2: what about this?**

```
List<int> checkList = new List<int>();
int[] firstList = new int[list1.Count];
int[] scndList = new int[list2.Count];
// Structure data
for (var i = 0; i < firstList.Length; i++)
{
    firstList[list1.Fvalue] = list1.intValue;
    scndList[list2.Fvalue] = list2.intValue;
    // Fvalue is that f, you can use substring and int parsing for that.
}

for (var i = 0; i < list1.Count; i++)
{
    if (firstList[index] != scndList[index])
    {
        checkList.Add(firstList[index]);
    }
}
// checkList will be your answer.
```

Comment: This would work if I didn't have to take into account added/removed items. Because two values may have different indexes but due to the fact that an item has been removed, it is still in the same order. Hence why I thought of first verifying the previous and next values. :S

Comment: I edited the question to clarify what I meant by Added or Removed Value. Thank you for your help but I dont think just checking the indexes would work